# Do Until Loop with Group by in SAS

Tags: sas, do-loops

I'm trying to run a do until loop in SAS for a set of stores with different SKU's and DCs to find a TSF_Qty for each SKU/DC combination.  I am trying to sum up the SKU/DC's TSF_QTY as SUM_TSF_QTY and change the increment_percent until the SUM_TSF_QTY is greater than or equal to the netdcinv.

I was able to figure out how to sum the SKU's by DC, but found that when running the do until loop that it runs all stores at a 1.25 increment then only runs the do loop for one store causing a very high increment_percent.  Can anyone help me figure out how to have it run the do loop for the entire store set and then sum it back up by sku_dc?

```
data Test3;
    set TSF_Data (drop=location);
    increment_percent=1;
    do until(SUM_TSF_QTY>=netdcinv);
        increment_percent=increment_percent+.25;
        New_Max_Stock = (Increment_Percent * max_stock);
        Need1 = (New_Max_Stock-Stock_on_hand);
        need2 = round(need1,1);
        Need3 = (need2/inner_pack_size);
        Need4 = round(need3,1);
        Final_Need = (need4*inner_pack_size);
        if need1>0
            then TSF_Qty = max(inner_pack_size,Final_Need);
            else TSF_Qty=0;
        by SKU_DC;
        if first.SKU_DC then Sum_TSF_Qty=tsf_qty;
        Sum_TSF_Qty+TSF_Qty;
        if last.SKU_DC;
    end;
run;
```

Didn't know of a better way to show the Sample Data.  The first image is a sample of the input data.  The second image is the current output I am getting.  Since the do until is only running all stores once and then running the last store the increment_percent is much higher than desired.

[Input and Output Sample Data Sets](http://imgur.com/Kked4MC&8V5cWLF#0)

Thanks

Comment: Posting the problematic code is a good first step, but if you also post a dummy input dataset and the corresponding desired output dataset, that  will make this much easier to investigate.

Comment: Could you explain your acronyms, please?

Comment: Yes, dummy data will help people understand what you want. A wild guess is to replace if last.sku_dc; with if last.sku_dc then output;  As written, it's a sub setting IF, which wall cause control to exit the do loop prematurely. But that's just a wild guess, since I'm not sure what you want as desired result.